# Unity 2D axe throw that stick on walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

The thing is I already made the axe throwing. The problem is how can I make the axe stick on wall position? When the axe hit the wall, its not the head of the axe, sometimes its the handle or the back of the axe.
Sorry for bad English. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The axe should consist of two separate meshes so you can use two MeshColliders, one for the handle and one for the blade. If it's one mesh, you can create two empty GameObjects as children give them primitive colliders to approximate the mesh.

The hierarchy of the axe prefab should look like this:

Axe (Rigidbody)

- Handle (MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, MeshCollider)
- Blade (MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, MeshCollider)

Or this:

Axe (Rigidbody, MeshFilter, MeshRenderer)

- Handle

  - PrimitiveCollider1 (e.g. SphereCollider)
  - PrimitiveCollider2 (e.g. BoxCollider)
- Blade

  - Also just primitive colliders to approximate its shape

I hope the axe throw is via physics so it's already looking good when the handle hits the wall?

For the blade to stick to the wall add a script like this to the Blade in the hierarchy above:

```
public DisableRigidbodyOnCollision
{
    [SerializeField] private new Rigidbody rigidbody; // assign in the inspector

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // add check if we hit the wall and not something else
        // e.g. via the name, tag or layer of collision.gameObject
        rigidbody.enabled = false;
        // alternatively, freeze the rigidbody or make it's velocity 0 and make it not be affected by gravity, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate it. But the thing is, I'm doing it on 2D and Not 3D.
To be honest I wanna recreate the Axe Throwing Mechanics of the New God Of War Axe Throw and Return in 2D. ^_^

which is this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-3P59GtRW4

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's 2D or 3D. Just use the hierarchy I outlined with 2D primitive colliders. If the blade hits the wall, the axe should stick to the wall, right? And what should happen if the handle hits the wall?